# Method For Ending A Loop With Completion Handler?

Tags: arrays, swift, loops, completionhandler

Perhaps I have an underlying issue understanding the overall premise, but I am trying to figure out the best approach to *do something* with an array of items, and end the *test* early once a certain criteria is found.

For example, I have an array of names;
`var names = ["Bob", "Billy", "Sarah", "Brandon", "Brian", "Rick"]`

I would like to test each name in the array and see if it exists in a database.  To do this, I'm calling another function with a completion handler;

```
for name in names {

    TestName(name) { response in

     if response {
         // END THE LOOP
     } else {
         // KEEP GOING
     }
 }
```

I've not been able to figure out the **// END THE LOOP**.  For the purposes of this example, I'm only concerned when the response is true the first time (if Billy exists in the array, I have no further interest in testing Sarah, Brandon, Brian, or Rick).

Thank you!

Comment: Sorry about my bad answer. The problem here is that you are in a block that I didn't notice. :)

Comment: By the way, if TestName's completion handler is asynchronous, you _do_ have an underlying issue with your overall premise!

Comment: FYI, if this is meant to be synchronous, you shouldn't be using a closure and if it's meant to be asynchronous, you can't count on your desired behavior using a for loop

Comment: Is `TestName` an asynchronous method? Or is it synchronous? If synchronous, there are better, simpler patterns than the closure pattern. If asynchronous (as one might infer from the "completion handler" terminology) then something very, very different is called for (e.g. some complex design to cancel the other tasks).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before you start the loop, set a flag:

```
var exitEarly = false
for name in names {
```

Test the flag each time thru the loop:

```
for name in names {
    if exitEarly {
        break
    }
```

In the TestName response block, set the flag:

```
TestName(name) { response in
    if response {
        exitEarly = true
    } else {
        // KEEP GOING
    }
}
```

Note, however, that if TestName's block is executed asynchronously, that won't work, because the whole loop precedes the calling of any of the asynchronous blocks (that is the nature of asynchronous-ness).

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for.  It worked for my needs; I was having a hard time theorizing how to break the loop, but this worked well.

Comment: Matt, in your 2nd code block above didn't you mean to say `for name in names {if exitEarly {break}}` rather than `if name in names...`?

Comment: while not being "wrong" with the apparent use case, assuming a closure will be executed synchronously, is a pretty bad assumption/habit

Comment: If this closure ran synchronously (which is unlikely given that he's called it a "completion handler"), it would be simpler if he just had `TestName` return a value (on the basis of either a closure return type or an `inout` parameter). Or, perhaps better, he should jettison the closure pattern altogether. But, it's probably moot, as it's likely asynchronous, in which case this all falls apart.

Comment: @Rob Agreed. The pattern itself is fairly vile.

Comment: For my use case, this example worked perfectly.  While I do recognize that there are other probable solutions, especially given whether `TestName()` is  or is not asynchronous, this helped me immensely and I was trying to come up with a rationale for this type of setup.

Comment: @ZbadhabitZ - Using the "completion handler" closure makes perfect sense if initiating an asynchronous process, but is an awkward design for synchronous processes (as there are far simpler, more elegant approaches). The problem is, though, that if your method _is_ asynchronous, then all of these answers about how to cancel the tasks initiated by `TestName` are simply not applicable. Everyone assumed it must have been synchronous on the basis of how you worded the question.

Answer (score 1):

Your case isn't really what a loop is designed for. It's possible that the loop may finish before the closures within the loop are executed.

Instead, try a recursive function with a completion block:

```
func databaseHasAName(names: [String], index: Int, completion: (String?) -> ()) {

    guard index < names.count else{
        completion(nil)
        return
    }

    let name = names[index]
    TestName(name) { response in

        if response {
            completion(name)
        } else {
            databaseHasName(names, index: index + 1, completion: completion)
        }
    }
}
```

This insures that only one call is happening at a time, regardless of the synchronicity of the response block

Answer (score 0):

1. Add the `@noescape` attribute to TestName's closure parameter to indicate that the closure does not escape the call.
2. Use a variable outside the TestName call, set to false, and set it to true inside the loop if you want to stop.
3. After the TestName call, check the variable to see if you need to break.

or

1. Change TestName to return a value indicating if it should proceed or not

Answer (score 0):

I had to do the same thing as PEEJWEEJ.  My async tasks are web queries and parsing and quite intensive and the for loop always finished before those tasks did so there was no way to stop them.

So I converted it to recursive and set a flag when I wanted it to stop and it works fine now.

```
// ************************************************************************************************************
// MARK: Recursive function
// I changed the loop to be recursive so I could stop when I need to - i.e. when selecting another race
// I set the stopFetching flag in the seque when changing races and the current set of BG queries stops
// ************************************************************************************************************
func getRaceResultsRecursive(race: Race, bibs: [Bib], index: Int, completion: @escaping (Bool?) -> ())
{
    guard index < bibs.count else{
        completion(nil)
        return
    }

    var url: URL
    self.stopFetching = false

    let bibID = bibs[index]
        url = self.athleteResultAPI.formatURL(baseURL: (race.baseURL)!,
                                              rd: (race.rdQueryItem)!,
                                              race: (race.raceQueryItem)!,
                                              bibID: "\(bibID.bib!)",
            detail: (race.detailQueryItem)!,
            fragment: (race.detailQueryItem)!,
            webQueryType: (race.webQueryType!))

    self.athleteResultAPI.fetchAthleteResults(url: url, webQueryType: race.webQueryType!)
    {
        (athleteReturnCode) in
        switch athleteReturnCode
        {
        case let .success(athleteResult):
            self.athleteResults.append(athleteResult)       // Add to collection
            self.delegate?.athleteResultsUpdated()           // update Delegate to notify of change
        case let .failure(error):
            print(error)
            break
        }

        if self.stopFetching {
            completion(true)
        }
        else {
            self.getRaceResultsRecursive(race: race, bibs: bibs, index: index + 1, completion: completion)
        }
    }
}

// ************************************************************************************************************
// getRaceResults
// Get all the bibs to track for this race from the iCloudKit database
// ************************************************************************************************************
func getRaceResults(race: Race)
{
    // get all the races and bibs an put in the Races Store
    raceStore.fetchBibsForRace(race: race, foreignKey: race.recordID)
    {
        (results, error) in
        if let error = error {
            print("Error in fetchBibsForRace(): \(error)")
            return
        }

        // clear the store since we are on a new race
        self.athleteResults.removeAll()
        self.getRaceResultsRecursive(race: race, bibs: race.bibs, index: 0)
        {
            (stopFetching) in
            return
        }

    }
}
```